# web3.js token approve function show null / 0 in Metamask

Tags: web3js, metamask, dapp-development, dapps, jquery

**EDIT**
The allowance is set, the issue is just that metamask detect no token name nor amount that is allowed.

**In my HTML/JS**

```
amount = parseInt(web3.toWei(amount, "ether" ));

tokeninstance.approve(mainadd,amount,function(error, transactionHash){
if (!error){
    $("#allowanceresult").html("TX hash: "+transactionHash+"<br>")
    toastr.success("Approval successfull!")
}else{
    $("#allowanceresult").html("Error: "+error+"<br>")
    toastr.error("Approval failed!");
}
```

**In Solidity interface**

```
function approve(address guy, uint wad) public returns (bool);
```

Doing the approve function in remix manually work, I'm on ropsten, but using metamask + the HTML/JS dapp function up there, getting user input (show correctly in wei) and input predefined address (correct format), metamask show me this, still on ropsten:

[image]

Am I missing something? It's always like that I made my send() web3.js functions, I use the same web3.js file than I always do.

Checking on ropsten both side by side Event (from remix and metamask), it's clearly both same data inputed, same address and same wei ammount. :(

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

When calling a smart contract function from javascript, send the `uint` argument as a [BigNumber](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/). I guess you can try that?

`amount = new BigNumber(web3.toWei(amount, "ether" ));`

Comment: Yup I did, the allowance method is working in the UI

Comment: What I fon't understand is metamask showing undefined token/amount allowed

Comment: Can you try doing "Add Custom Token" in metamask?

Comment: I tried but it weirdly disappeared when I closed and opened back metamask. I'll  retry in the morning, it have sense theses data used when interacting with the token and showing data to metamask ui!